# Terraform import and using ip address as attribute name

Tags: terraform

I am building terrform.tfstate files from Terraform managed Fortigate devices. After producing output JSON files using Terraform output and a custom script to produce tf.address.tf.json, I wish to import the objects using the attribute name as outputted if possible.

With a tf.address.tf.json file structured like this

```
{
    "resource": {
        "fortios_firewall_address": {
            "11.0.0.0/8": {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I perform the following

`$ terraform import fortios_firewall_address.11_0_0_0/8 "11.0.0.0/8"`

which produces the error

```
Error: Attribute name required
│
│   on <import-address> line 1:
│    1: fortios_firewall_address.11_0_0_0/8
│
│ Dot must be followed by attribute name.
```

I suppose I need to alter the attribute name to something like "ADDRESS-11_0_0_0M8" but want to ask if there is another way to use the name as "fortios_firewall_address.11_0_0_0/8" in terrform import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've encountered here is not specific to `terraform import` but rather a general Terraform language rule: the name of a resource must be a valid identifier, and valid identifiers can start only with letters and underscores, not with digits.